# Override ModelAttribute with Path Variable in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm developing API using Spring Framework and faced a problem that can be solved by simply adding a necessary logic to every place I have it, but I think that there might be an elegant solution to fix it.

I have the following method in my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/user/{userId}/permissions")
public List<PermissionDto> list(@PathVariable long userId,
                                @ModelAttribute @Valid PermissionCriteria criteria) {
    return permissionService.list(criteria);
}
```

The thing is that in dto I have a field called userId. It's made not to have a lot of arguments going to the method of the service. But, I want this user id to be set exactly from path since I use the URL that specifies that we are adding permission exactly to specific user resource. It's doable by making addition line that uses setter in the criteria and sets the value of userId. However, now I should never forget to add this line every time I have a case like that. That's why I decided to move it to InitBinder:

```
@InitBinder(PERMISSIONS_CRITERIA_NAME)
public void permissionsCriteriaInitBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    PermissionsCriteria criteria = (PermissionsCriteria) binder.getTarget();
    Optional.ofNullable(requestHelper.getUserId())
            .map(Long::parseLong)
            .ifPresent(criteria::setUserId);
}
```

It works fine. The user ID is set from the path. However, If I specify request parameter and path variable at the same time, even though userId is set from the path in init binder, it's overridden afterwards before it goes to the controller method. So, this one doesn't solve all the issues. 
What I want to find, is someplace where the logic can be put to apply to both init binder(I need it for validation) and controller method. Maybe there is a special type of hook or interceptor or at least something to implement to satisfy this conditions?